# Validate entry of an input box

Tags: validation, excel, inputbox, vba

Im trying to get an input box to validate the entries a user will make.

i'm using the below script but cant get the validation to work, any help would be appreciated.

```
 Sub inputbox()

 Dim Manager As Long

     On Error Resume Next

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Manager = Application.inputbox(Prompt:="Please enter a manager.", Title:="Pick A Manager Name",      Type:=1)

On Error GoTo 0

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    If Manager = "" Then

        Exit Sub

    ElseIf Manager <> Ben, Cameron, Chris, Martin, Peter Then

    MsgBox "Incorrect Name, pick a new one!"

    Else

        MsgBox "Your input was " & Manager

    End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although a Sub name same as built in ones are not recommended, you can do what you are after like below.

First you need to change the InputBox **Type** to **2** (String), since you are comparing with String. Then you should make a function to check if the input is part of a Manager List.

```
Sub inputbox()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Manager As String

    Manager = Application.inputbox(Prompt:="Please enter a manager name:", Title:="Pick A Manager Name", Type:=2)

    If Manager <> "" Then
        If IsManager(Manager) Then
            MsgBox "Your input was " & Manager
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Name, pick a new one!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsManager(sTxt As String) As Boolean
    Dim aManagers As Variant, oItem As Variant, bAns As Boolean
    aManagers = Array("Ben", "Cameron", "Chris", "Martin", "Peter")
    bAns = False
    For Each oItem In aManagers
        If LCase(oItem) = LCase(Trim(sTxt)) Then
            bAns = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    IsManager = bAns
End Function
```

**UPDATE (Improved version suggested by Simon1979):**

```
Private Function IsManager(sTxt As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim aManagers As Variant
    aManagers = Array("Ben", "Cameron", "Chris", "Martin", "Peter")
    IsManager = Not IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Trim(sTxt), aManagers, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: I like the use of array, I should have caught that one. Rather than looping through the array you could also use `If IsError(Application.Match(Trim(sTxt), aManagers, False)) Then`, returns true if the entry was NOT in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! To other readers: it should be `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used the InputBox with Excel but I imagine it will be very similar to the Access one. I use the below method to validate inputbox:

```
Dim strM as string

EnterManager:
strM = InputBox("Enter Manager.")
If StrPtr(strM) = 0 Then 'Cancel was pressed
    ' Handle what to do if cancel pressed
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Len(strM) = 0 Then 'OK was pressed with nothing entered
    MsgBox "You must enter a Manager."
    GoTo EnterBuyer
End If
```

To add your criteria you could add on another `If`, I'm not sure you can use the approach you have for checking the list of names. Also don't understand how you compare a long `Manager` with a list of names `Ben, Cameron, Chris, Martin, Peter`, unless they are assigned variables, in which case I would suggest adding prefixes so it is more obvious such as `lBen` as opposed to `strBen` so you can easily see the difference in variable type.

```
If strM <> "Ben" And strM <> "Cameron" And strM <> "Chris" And strM <> _
    "Martin" And strM <> "Peter" Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect Name, pick a new one!"
Else
    MsgBox "Your input was " & strM
End If
```

Comment: OK looks good, how do i then have the value of strM entered into sheets called "PID" in cell "G9". thanks.